# Return template type from template class

Tags: c++, templates

I'm getting errors trying to get the below code to work

```
template<typename var>
struct Point
{
    var x;
    var y;

    constexpr Point() : x( 0 ), y( 0 ) {
    }
    constexpr Point( const var _x, const var _y ) : x( _x ), y( _y ) {
    }
    var GetX() const { return x; }
    var GetY() const { return y; }
};

template<typename var>
struct Rect
{
    var x, y;
    var w, h;

    constexpr Rect() : x( 0 ), y( 0 ), w( 0 ), h( 0 ) {
    }
    constexpr Rect( const var _x, const var _y, const var _w, const var _h ) : x(_x), y(_y), w(_w), h(_h) {
    }

    var Left() const { return x; }
    var Right() const { return x + w; }
    var Top() const { return y; }
    var Bottom() const { return y + h; }
    Point<var> LT() const { return Point<var>( x, y ) };
    Point<var> RT() const { return Point<var>( x + w, y ) };
    Point<var> LB() const { return Point<var>( x, y + h ) };
    Point<var> RB() const { return Point<var>( x + w, y + h ) };
};
```

The Point < var > returns in my struct Rect seem to be causing a lot of difficult to understand errors. Would anyone happen to know the proper way of doing this?

Comment: Which errors? It helps to include them in the question.

Comment: It amazes that you don't paste the entire error in your question, a standard practice, considering your experience here

Comment: @chris I did not include the error as it seemed to add little value to the question. The exact error being spit out by MSVC being that any file that included the above file having syntax errors, while showing no error related to the above file. 
I felt adding the error(s) would merely clutter the question and add confusion, with people asking me to then include the other files that MSVC was talking about, while I can clearly see there is nothing wrong with the other files. If people however would prefer that I regardless add the error, please let me know.

Comment: @PasserBy please refer to my comment above to Chris.

Comment: FWIW, pasting the code into http://gcc.godbolt.org gives really straightforward errors with both GCC and Clang. It's usually worth trying out different compilers when it's that easy.

Comment: The error message will still be informative, of for no other reason than people getting good at deciphering MSVC arcana. If you are certain it is contained within this file, then you should create a mcve in a single file as proof, and at the same time debugging for yourself. This isn't formalities, this is saving time for everyone involved

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is no semicolon after:

```
return Point <var> (x,y)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. While after seeing this answer I immediately went 'Ah', and realised how careless a miss I made, I might have spent another couple of hours had the answerer not posted this. Thank you!

Comment: However, after 4+ years on StackOverflow, I find it discouraging seeing how many people seem to now more like voting down questions based on general rules and preformed perceptions, than wanting to help out someone facing trouble. Thank you again for being an example of the few that still put priority on wanting to help - this really helped.